# GROUP_CONCAT and LEFT_JOIN issue - Not all rows returned

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, group-concat

Let's say my DB Scheme is as follows:

```
T_PRODUCT
id_product (int, primary)

two entries: (id_product =1) , (id_product =2)

T_USER
id_user (int, primary)
id_product (int, foreign key)
name_user (varchar)

two entries: (id_product=1,name_user='John') , (id_product=1,name_user='Mike')
```

If I run a first query to get all products with their users (if there are any), I get this:

```
SELECT T_PRODUCT.id_product, T_USER.name_user 
FROM T_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN T_USER on T_USER.id_product = T_PRODUCT.id_product;

>>
id_product name_user
1          John
1          Mike
2          NULL
```

Looks good to me.
Now if I want to the same thing, except I'd like to have one product per line, with concatenated user names (if there are any users, otherwise NULL):

```
SELECT T_PRODUCT.id_product, GROUP_CONCAT(T_USER.name_user) 
FROM T_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN T_USER on T_USER.id_product = T_PRODUCT.id_product;

>>
id_product name_user
1          John,Mike

**expected output**:
id_product name_user
1          John,Mike
2          NULL
```

If there are no users for a product, the GROUP_CONCAT prevents mysql from producing a line for this product, even though there's a **LEFT JOIN**.

1. Is this an expected MySQL behaviour?
2. Is there any way I could get the expected output using GROUP_CONCAT or another function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, found my answer:

You should never forget the **GROUP BY** clause when working with **GROUP_CONCAT**.
I was missing `GROUP BY T_PRODUCT.id_product` in my second query.

I'll leave the question up in case someone is as absent-minded as I am.

*Edit*:

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645921/mysql-group-by-behavior/1646121#1646121), I figured I can also activate the SQL Mode [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode%5Fonly%5Ffull%5Fgroup%5Fby) to force MySQL to throw an error in case the GROUP BY is missing or incorrect.

Comment: MySql doesn't complain when you leave out a group by?  I believe T-Sql and Oracle both do...

Comment: @jle: MySQL is lax on the `GROUP BY` clause by design

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645921/mysql-group-by-behavior/1646121#1646121

Comment: Thank you Bill, now I know I can use the sql mode "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" to make it behave like the other RDBMS and throw an error when the GROUP BY is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could use a subquery, just test for performance

```
SELECT 
  T_PRODUCT.id_product, 
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T_USER.name_user) 
     FROM T_USER 
     WHERE T_USER.id_product = T_PRODUCT.id_product
  )
FROM T_PRODUCT
```