# issue with GROUP_CONCAT in JOIN query mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat

I have a join query where I left join 2 tables say `tab_sector`and `tab_sector_subdivisions`. I have records in first table which may or may not have corresponding records in 2nd table. I am joining these tables in such a way that Its should return all row from first table and matching row from 2nd table. Also if a row in first table has multiple record in 2nd table, it should return as `GROUP_CONCAT(field_name)`. But my query doesn't return the way I need.

Here is the query without GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT tab_sector.sector_id,tab_sector.sector_title,tab_sector.sector_desc,tab_sector.sector_image,tab_sector_subdivisions.subdiv_id 
FROM tab_sector 
LEFT JOIN tab_sector_subdivisions 
ON tab_sector_subdivisions.sector_id = tab_sector.sector_id WHERE tab_sector.active = 'Y'
```

the result is:
[image]

you can see 2 rows for id 20. What I need is single row but `subdiv_id` as `(19,20)`. Then I used GROUP_CONCAT in the query like:

```
    SELECT tab_sector.sector_id,tab_sector.sector_title,tab_sector.sector_desc,tab_sector.sector_image,GROUP_CONCAT(tab_sector_subdivisions.subdiv_id) 
FROM tab_sector 
LEFT JOIN tab_sector_subdivisions 
ON tab_sector_subdivisions.sector_id = tab_sector.sector_id WHERE tab_sector.active = 'Y'
```

Then the result will be :

[image]

My other two records are missing in this. I want that rows too in my result.

Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: group_concat is an aggregate operator & aggregate operators use group by (implicitly if not explicitly). This is a faq & you would have found an answer if, as you always should, you googled many clear precise phrasings of your problem/question/goal. Eg just 'GROUP_CONCAT in JOIN query mysql rows missing'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP\_CONCAT and LEFT\_JOIN issue - Not all rows returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653195/group-concat-and-left-join-issue-not-all-rows-returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  the group by for the not aggregated  columns

```
SELECT tab_sector.sector_id,tab_sector.sector_title,tab_sector.sector_desc
    ,tab_sector.sector_image,group_concat(tab_sector_subdivisions.subdiv_id )
LEFT JOIN tab_sector_subdivisions 
        ON tab_sector_subdivisions.sector_id = tab_sector.sector_id 
              AND tab_sector.active = 'Y'
GROUP BY  tab_sector.sector_id,tab_sector.sector_title,
     tab_sector.sector_desc, tab_sector.sector_image
```

Answer (score 0):

group by missed that`s why it is returning one record,

```
  SELECT tab_sector.sector_id,tab_sector.sector_title,tab_sector.sector_desc,tab_sector.sector_image,GROUP_CONCAT(tab_sector_subdivisions.subdiv_id) 
FROM tab_sector 
LEFT JOIN tab_sector_subdivisions 
ON tab_sector_subdivisions.sector_id = tab_sector.sector_id WHERE tab_sector.active = 'Y'
group by tab_sector.sector_id,tab_sector.sector_title,tab_sector.sector_desc,tab_sector.sector_image;
```