# SQL greatest-n-per-group with relational table joins

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables. image, categories, image_category.

```
image:         id | title | imageURL
categories:     cat_id | cat_name
image_category: image_id | cat_id
```

My current query to select all images in order newest to oldest is:

```sql
SELECT image.id as ID, image.title as title, categories.cat_name as CAT 
FROM image_category 
LEFT JOIN image 
ON image_category.image_id = image.id 
INNER JOIN categories 
ON image_category.cat_id = categories.cat_id 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

I would like to show the newest 4 images per category. The largest image.id are the newest images.

For example. If I had 3 categories and 40 images in each category. I want to show the newest 4 images from each category. I will later be trying to show the next 4 per category after that and then the next 4 per category until there are no images left.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category) solution seems like what im looking for.

```sql
SELECT i1.*
FROM item i1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item i2
ON (i1.category_id = i2.category_id AND i1.item_id < i2.item_id)
GROUP BY i1.item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY category_id, date_listed;
```

but I have a relational table connecting my image_id and category_id. Cant figure out how to implement this with that extra table join.

Would appreciate help from an SQL guru.

Comment: Please post table schemas and sample data

Comment: can an image have many categories? (since it looks like a many-to-many relation)

Comment: greatest n per group ?? group by what?? and what is the criteria to be greatest?

Comment: do you want greatest n image IDs per category??

Comment: I would like to show the newest 4 images per category. The largest image.id are the newest images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to do the grouping using your `item_category` table since that's where the cat_id's are.

```
SELECT ...
FROM item_category AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_category AS c2
  ON c1.cat_id = c2.cat_id AND c1.image_id < c2.image_id
GROUP BY c1.cat_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
```

Then once you've got that, you know that `c1` contains the top four images per category.  You can then join `c1` to the `image` table to get other attributes:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, c.cat_name AS CAT 
FROM item_category AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_category AS c2
  ON c1.cat_id = c2.cat_id AND c1.image_id < c2.image_id
INNER JOIN image AS on c1.image_id = i.id
INNER JOIN categories AS c on c1.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY c1.image_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4;
```

Although this isn't strictly legal SQL due to the [*single-value rule*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645921/mysql-group-by-behavior/1646121#1646121), MySQL will permit it.

---

Copied from comments thread:

I would fetch the full result, store it in a cache, and then iterate over it however I want, using application code. That would be far simpler and have better performance. SQL is powerful, but another solution may be easier to develop, debug, and maintain.

You can certainly use `LIMIT` to iterate through the result set:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, c.cat_name AS CAT 
FROM item_category AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_category AS c2
  ON c1.cat_id = c2.cat_id AND c1.image_id < c2.image_id
INNER JOIN image AS on c1.image_id = i.id
INNER JOIN categories AS c on c1.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY c1.image_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY c.cat_id
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 16;
```

But keep in mind that doing an OFFSET means that it has to run the query over again each time you view another set of them.  There are optimizations in MySQL so that it quits a query once it has found enough rows, but it's still expensive if you iterate frequently, and advance far into the series of pages.

Two possible optimizations you can use:  One is to cache *part* of the result, on the theory that few users will want to advance through every page of a large paginated result.  So for example, fetch enough to populate ten pages worth of results, and cache that.  It reduces the number of queries a lot, and perhaps only 1% of the times will user advance into the next set of ten pages.

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, c.cat_name AS CAT 
FROM item_category AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_category AS c2
  ON c1.cat_id = c2.cat_id AND c1.image_id < c2.image_id
INNER JOIN image AS on c1.image_id = i.id
INNER JOIN categories AS c on c1.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY c1.image_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY c.cat_id
LIMIT 40 OFFSET 40; /* second set of ten pages */
```

Another optimization, if you can assume that any view of page `N` will be coming from a view of page `N-1`, is for the request to filter the categories based on the greatest category id seen in the `N-1`<sup>st</sup> page.  You need to do it this way because OFFSET works by row number in the result set, but indexed offsets work by values found on those rows.  These aren't the same offset if there may be gaps or unused cat_id values.

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, c.cat_name AS CAT 
FROM item_category AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_category AS c2
  ON c1.cat_id = c2.cat_id AND c1.image_id < c2.image_id
INNER JOIN image AS on c1.image_id = i.id
INNER JOIN categories AS c on c1.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c1.cat_id > 47 /* this value is the largest seen in previous page */ 
GROUP BY c1.image_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY c.cat_id
LIMIT 40; /* no offset needed */
```

---

Re your comments:

> ... using LIMIT and OFFSET will only trim those results and not move me down the list of rows.

`LIMIT` is working as intended; it applies to the resulting rows *after* `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` have done their work.

> The way I was doing it before the greatest N per category query is by
>   1. pulling in x amount of images,
>   2. Remembering which was the last image, and then
>   3. using a sub query on my subsequent queries to get the next x amount of images with ids smaller than than the last image. Is something like that possible with greatest N per group?

That's what my `WHERE` clause does in the last example above, without using a subquery.  And I'm assuming you're advancing to the next *higher* set of cat_id's.  This solution works only if you're advancing one page at a time, and in the positive direction.

---

All right, there's another solution for greatest-n-per-group that works with MySQL, but it relies on the user variables feature.  SQLite doesn't have this feature.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.id as image_ID, p.imageURL as URL, c.cat_name as CAT, ic.cat_id,
    IF(@cat=ic.cat_id, @row:=@row+1, @row:=1) AS _row, @cat:=ic.cat_id AS _cat
  FROM (SELECT @cat:=null, @row:=0) AS _init
  CROSS JOIN image_category AS ic
  INNER JOIN portfolio AS p ON ic.image_id = p.id
  INNER JOIN categories AS c on ic.cat_id = c.cat_id
  ORDER BY ic.cat_id, ic.image_id
) AS x
WHERE _row BETWEEN 4 AND 6;  /* or choose any range you want */
```

This is similar to using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat_id)` that is supported by standard SQL and most RDBMS, but SQLite doesn't support that either yet.

Comment: do you know if its sqlite friendly? I cant seem to get it to work. Not sure if its my mistake or not supported.

Comment: An `i` is missing. `INNER JOIN image AS on ...`  should be `INNER JOIN image AS i on ...`

Comment: Thx Bill, do you know if it's possible to make one query that could  iterate through the entire db showing groups of 4 images per category at a time (as long as they exist). Im assuming it would need to be fed the previous queries last image id's from each category and then perform a variant of this answers query. If I made a new question would you take a stab?

Comment: @BillKarwin I would have thought holding the entire db of rows in cache would hinder performance (at a certain load). I would like to lazy load images and would ideally present a balanced set of images per category per query. There's no simple way you know of to play with WHERE and/or HAVING to do this?

Comment: See additional content above.

Comment: thanks so much for the extra info, I really appreciate your attention. My test using LIMIT and OFFSET don't seem to give the desired result as HAVING COUNT(*) < 4 (for example) limits the results to 4 images per category and using LIMIT and OFFSET will only trim those results and not move me down the list of rows.

Comment: The way I was doing it before the greatest N per category query is by 1. pulling in x amount of images, 2. Remembering which was the last image and then 3. using a sub query on my subsequent queries to get the next x amount of images with ids smaller than than the last image. Is something like that possible with greatest N per group?

Comment: @BillKarwin apologize for the dragged on question... Please ignore me if this is too much. Im a front end guy trying to make sense of this.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think we may be on slightly separate pages. If you could take a look at this sqlfiddle with sample data it should clarify. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a8369/6 Using "WHERE" I could not get the next 9 results (3 from each category). As in the next 3 images in cat 3d, next 3 images in illustration, next 3 images in photography.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT a.id as ID,a.title as title,b.cat_name as CAT, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY b.cat_id ORDER BY b.cat_id,a.id desc) AS n
   from images a, categories b, image_category c 
    where a.id = c.image_id
    and b.cat_id = c.cat_id
) x
WHERE n < 4
ORDER BY b.cat_id,a.id desc;
```

Comment: maybe this works but i kept getting errors about unrecognized token ":" thanks for answering tho