# Count the number of exists and not exist using MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am trying to list out all task with the count of finished/completed task (In submissions). The problem is that I also want to show all task that no users have finished. This query does not list out count = 0 (Null). Is there any way to do this?

Wanted result:

```
Date       | title   | completed
2014-05-20 | Case  1 | 45
2014-05-24 | Case 10 | 11
2014-05-20 | Case  2 |  0
```

I have tried so far:

```
Select date, title, count(*) as completed
from users u, submissions s, task t
where u.userPK = s.user
and s.task= t.taskPK
group by taskPK
order by completed desc;
```

[image: Tables]

Comment: To which table does `date` and `title` belong?

Comment: Date and title belongs to the table task.

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output, don't really understand you expected result.

Comment: I want to list out the number of completed task, and the task that is not completed. Represented by (0 or null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to achive this using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT date, title, COUNT(u.userPK) completed FROM task t 
LEFT JOIN submissions s ON s.task = t.taskPK 
LEFT JOIN users u ON s.user = u.userPK 
GROUP BY t.taskPK 
ORDER BY completed;
```

Comment: Please stop encouraging bad `GROUP BY` practice.

Comment: @Kermit - I just keept the `GROUP` and `ORDER` clauses as they were. Edited my answer though.

Comment: @Kermit - Also, I'm not really sure why the above group by clause is considered bad practice, can you explain?

Comment: @KristerAndersson [MySQL GROUP BY behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646121/679449) and [Why does MySQL add a feature that conflicts with SQL standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7594865/679449)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `OUTER JOIN` to get your desired results.  However, considering the previous answer didn't suffice, I would also guess you don't want to `GROUP BY` the `taskPK` field, but rather by the `date` and `title` fields.

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t.date, t.title, count(*) cnt
FROM task t
    LEFT JOIN submissions s ON t.task = s.taskPK
GROUP BY t.date, t.title
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I also removed the `user` table as I'm not sure how it affects the results.  If you need it back, just add an additional join.