# Set a Boolean as a mysql record indicates if other record exists before chosen timeStamp range

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, window-functions

**basic table is similar to:**

```html
mysqlTable:
          visitorID   ,park          ,DateTimeStamp
          8369        ,Birmingham    ,12/27/2018 03:26:38 PM
          8369        ,Birmingham    ,12/28/2018 11:27:32 AM
          8828        ,Central       ,01/02/2019 10:01
          8828        ,Central       ,01/04/2019 9:50
          8825        ,Central       ,12/21/2018 09:47:27 AM
          8821        ,Central       ,12/26/2018 10:11:40 AM
          8821        ,Central       ,02/03/2019 10:00:59 AM
          8821        ,Central       ,01/02/2019 10:04
          88281       ,Central       ,01/04/2019 9:53
```

From this table i'm creating a new one where i'm counting visitor's ID in a specific park, then grouping the visits by the visitorID and the date of the visit in a specific period of time.

```html
mysql query: 

SELECT COUNT(*)AS visits,dateTimeStamp,visitorID 
FROM parkVisits 
WHERE 
    dateTimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2019-01-04 23:59:59'
    AND park ='Central'
GROUP BY visitorID, CAST(dateTimeStamp AS DATE);
```

**my result:**

```html
mysql table:

visits   ,dateTimeStamp     ,visitorID   
2        ,01/02/2019 10:01  ,8828      
1        ,01/02/2019 10:04  ,8821       
1        ,01/04/2019 9:53   ,88281
```

I would like to have a column where a Boolean indicates if the visitor has visited anytime before the specified date **of it's row.**
I was thinking about comparing the earliest dateTimeStamp on table to the earliest given date, but a situation can occur where the first visit and the returning visit occurred during the given period.

**expected:**

```html
mysql table:

visits   ,dateTimeStamp   ,visitorID    ,returningVisitor
2        ,01/02/2019 10:01,  8828       ,TRUE
1        ,01/02/2019 10:04,  8821       ,FALSE
1        ,01/04/2019 9:53,   88281      ,FALSE
```

**EDIT:**

i'm using MySQL 5.6.40

Comment: Since you're grouping by ``visitorID``, that means ``dateTimeStamp`` be basically an arbitrary value from all of that user's rows. MySQL may happen to return the first/earliest (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646121/378779) but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: You would need to better describe how to choose the  `dateTimestamp` when there are several visits in the period. How about the ealier visit in the period ? Or tmaybe the last one ?

Comment: First one is better. EDIT: on second taught it doesn’t matter, the yy:mm:dd is what’s important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are running MySQL 8.0, you could use an inner query with window function [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) to pick up the timestamp of the first visit in the analyzis period. Then in the outer query, an `EXISTS` clause with a subquery can be used to check if the current visitor has ever visited the same park before.

```
SELECT 
    x.visits,
    x.dateTimeStamp,
    x.visitorID,
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM parkVisits WHERE park = x.park AND visitorID = x.visitorID AND dateTimeStamp < x.dateTimeStamp
    ) returningVisitor
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.visitorID) visits,
        FIRST_VALUE(p.dateTimeStamp) OVER (PARTITION BY p.visitorID ORDER BY p.dateTimeStamp) dateTimeStamp,
        p.visitorID,
        p.park
    FROM parkVisits p
    WHERE
        p.dateTimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2019-01-04 23:59:59' 
        AND p.park ='Central'
) x
ORDER BY 1 desc, 2
```

In [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qABnoMBGnkTdBgyCbw7YF/1) with your sample data, it returns :

```
| visits | dateTimeStamp       | visitorID | returningVisitor |
| ------ | ------------------- | --------- | ---------------- |
| 2      | 2019-01-02 10:01:00 | 8828      | 0                |
| 1      | 2019-01-02 10:04:00 | 8821      | 1                |
| 1      | 2019-01-04 09:53:00 | 88281     | 0                |
```

NB : I think the returning visitor is `8821`, and not `8828` as shown in your question.

If you are running a lower version of MySQL, that does not support window functions, you can use a `GROUP BY` clause in the subquery, like :

```
SELECT 
    x.visits,
    x.dateTimeStamp,
    x.visitorID,
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM parkVisits WHERE park = x.park AND visitorID = x.visitorID AND dateTimeStamp < x.dateTimeStamp
    ) returningVisitor
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        COUNT(*) visits,
        MIN(p.dateTimeStamp) dateTimeStamp,
        p.visitorID,
        p.park
    FROM parkVisits p
    WHERE
        p.dateTimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2019-01-04 23:59:59' 
        AND p.park ='Central'
    GROUP BY p.visitorID, p.park
) x
ORDER BY 1 desc, 2
```

See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qABnoMBGnkTdBgyCbw7YF/2).

Comment: Nice!, but i'm using 5.6.40

Comment: @Anatsu : I updated my answer with a query for MySQL 5.x

Comment: Answered my question and as a bonus teached me something about the differences between 8.0 and 5.x. 
+1 AND V well deserved Sir!

Comment: Welcome @Anatsu !