# Differences in behavior of SELECT statements using MAX and SUM depending on MySQL version

Tags: mysql

There is a difference in results between MySQL5 and MySQL8 versions in a SELECT statement that uses an aggregate function.
I want to know the reason.

```
SELECT
A.student_id,
A.school_id,
max(B.number) AS max_number
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.student_id = A.student_id
WHERE A.student_id = 1
AND B.del_flg = 0
```

MySQL5

| A.student_id | A.school_id | max_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |

MySQL8

| A.student_id | A.school_id | max_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **NULL** | **NULL** | NULL |

I want to make sure that the result does not change even if the version is upgraded to MySQL8.

A simple SELECT statement without an aggregate function yields 0 rows in both MySQL versions.
However, using aggregate functions gives different results.

Are aggregate functions in MySQL 5 buggy?

Comment: You need a group by statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL GROUP BY behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645921/mysql-group-by-behavior)